# The namespace MicrosoftResearch.Infer.Learners.Mappings' already contains a definition forClassifierMappingExtensions'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I downloaded the [Infer.Net](http://infernet.azurewebsites.net/download.aspx) framework for running Bayesian inference in graphical models and imported it in my assets folder in Unity and got the following error:

> Assets/Infer.NET
>   2.7.1803.1901/Learners/Core/Mappings/ClassifierMappingExtensions.cs(15,25): error CS0101: The namespace
>   `MicrosoftResearch.Infer.Learners.Mappings' already contains a
>   definition for`ClassifierMappingExtensions'

Following is the version of C# in my Unity:
[image]

Please help

Answer (score 0):

The `Infer.NET` folder contains a Bin folder with dlls and a Learners folder with source code.  If you include both of these in the same project, then you will get a conflict where things are defined twice.